# How to modify my Swiper slide css ( I'm using the version 10.3.1 )

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

i'm using the Swiper on my website with react and nextjs, and i need to modify the bullets and buttons of the slider.

I watch some videos but they didn't work with me. Does someone know how to do this? I'm using css for the style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//components/SwiperDemo.js
import React from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css';
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper/core';

SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination]);

const SwiperDemo = ({ buttonStyles, dotStyles }) => {
  const swiperParams = {
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
  };

  return (
    <Swiper {...swiperParams}>
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/klMii3cR9iI" alt="Image 1" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/BfrQnKBulYQ" alt="Image 2" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/4hbJ-eymZ1o" alt="Image 3" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <div className="swiper-button-prev" style={buttonStyles}></div>
      <div className="swiper-button-next" style={buttonStyles}></div>
      <div className="swiper-pagination" style={dotStyles}></div>
    </Swiper>
  );
};

export default SwiperDemo;
```

and you can call your component with styles:

```
import SwiperDemo from '../components/SwiperDemo';

const Home = () => {
  const buttonStyles = {
    // Define your button styles here
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: 'white',
  };

  const dotStyles = {
    // Define your dot styles here
    // Example:
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    width: '10px',
    height: '10px',
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <SwiperDemo buttonStyles={buttonStyles} dotStyles={dotStyles} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

P.S don't forget to refactor my code according to you needs (check possible props for swiper [here](https://swiperjs.com/react#styles) )